# Scorekeeping a fielder on a Sacrifice Fly

Tags: rules, baseball, mlb

Currently I know that in a baseball game (Major League Baseball), a sacrifice fly is scored to the batter acting in an attempt to forfeit their attempt at a score (aka get on base) to allow someone else a chance to score (when there are less than two outs).

The question is does the fielder who catches the sac fly still get credit with a putout? I would like to say YES but the scorebook I'm using is showing empty box. I know that the batter is not credited as having an official at bat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the fielder gets credited with a putout.  Per the [MLB rulebook](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2015/official_baseball_rules.pdf), 9.09(a):

> (a) The official scorer shall credit a putout to each fielder who
>
> > (1) catches a ball that is in flight, whether fair or foul;
> >
> > (2) catches a batted or thrown ball and tags a base to put out
> >     a batter or runner; or
> >
> > > Rule 9.09(a)(2) Comment: The official scorer shall credit a
> > >       fielder with a putout if such fielder catches a thrown ball and
> > >       tags a base to record an out on an appeal play.
> >
> > (3) tags a runner when the runner is off the base to which the
> >     runner is entitled.

No exception is made for sacrifices of any sort.